# Angular metronic template error - Http failure response : 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angular, rxjs, metronic

login api takes two parameters : username, password
on checking in google chrome developer mode, following error appears

```
Http failure response for http://localhost:31557/api/Authenticate/login: 405 Method Not Allowed
(anonymous) @ intercept.service.ts:45
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error @ tap.js:55
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:59
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError @ 
OuterSubscriber.js:13
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error @ 
InnerSubscriber.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:59
onLoad @ http.js:1707
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
onInvokeTask @ core.js:26247
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:422
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1693
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1730
load (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1832
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
Show 174 more frames
```

Answer (score 1):

Method not allowed indicated that your backend is expecting a different HTTP verb. Usually one uses POST for login requests but this really depends on your backend. The stacktrace here is not really helpful.